# Should I correct factual error I made during interview?

Tags: interviewing

I am a doctor interviewing for a new job. Interviewer asked me how many beds the hospital I currently work at has. I guessed it is around 200 beds. I was only thinking the beds in my area of the practice. The hospital in fact has 700 beds in total. I found that out just by reading about the hospital website. Should I contact them and tell them about my errors and apologize? Probably "I don't know would've been a better answer.

Thank you

Comment: You guessed? So, you explicitly said something like "Oh, I dont' know the exact number but around 200"?

Comment: Also, what job are you applying to?

Comment: Will correcting make a difference in their perception of your skills/value added?

Comment: _"I found that out just by reading about the hospital website."_ What would bother me more than a wrongly specified number in an interview is the fact that you didn't know how many beds the clinic has that you have worked for as a doctor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The interviewer asked me how many beds there are in the hospital where I currently work.
>   Has

This question was asked to find out how big your hospital was, not to get the right number of beds. In this case, the difference between 200 and 700 is not that big. This clearly indicates that the hospital you worked at is quite large.

So I would not contact your interviewer in this case.

Answer (score 6):

I would be inclined to leave it alone. Probably they will not check. If they do, it is an easy error to make and does not reflect badly.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question depends on whether the fact *actually matters.*

In this case, I'd assume that your hospital has crossed the "Not small" threshold and there probably isn't much difference between 200 and 700 beds. **There is no need to bring it up**, especially if you properly conveyed that you were guessing how many beds. At the same time, **if** a chance comes up *naturally* in conversation, it wouldn't hurt to make the correction either.

If your job is to *clean* every bed, then 200 vs 700 might matter though!